# Retrieve user data from Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have created an Android App By which user can register and login.When a user registration is successful a Name and value will created in my database for that User. Now I want to retrieve The Data For every User separately.

[image: Here is my Database look:]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 mDatabase.child("ezzeearn").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            String point = map.get("Points");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
});
```

Comment: for more details, you can read from 
 https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the current user's data from this structure, you need two things:

1. to [know the uid of the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user)
2. to then [read the data from the database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events)

In code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance.getReference(uid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        long points = dataSnapshot.child("Points").getValue(Long.class);
     }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
});
```

Comment: i tried that but after login to my app, app unfortunately has stopped . i used this : long points = dataSnapshot.child("Points").getValue(long.class);
                Points.setText((int) points);

Comment: If the app crashed, there will be an exception+stack trace in your log cat that explains why it crashed. If you want to see whether it read the value from the snapshot correctly: `System.out.println(points);` and check in logcat.

Answer (score 0):

for using iterator you can get the data for specific user

```
Iterator<String> iter = json.keys();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String key = iter.next();
    try {
        Object value = json.get(key);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // Something went wrong!
    }
}
```

Comment: i didn't get u? can i use datasnapshot?

Comment: when you login you need to store your response this will help you to get the key

Comment: Did u see my database picture? would u plz write down the full code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below method :

```
     public void getAllUsersFromFirebase() {  
    DatabaseReference UserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ezzeearn");
    UserRef.keepSynced(true);
    UserRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override  
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Iterator<DataSnapshot> dataSnapshots = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

            while (dataSnapshots.hasNext()) {
                DataSnapshot dataSnapshotChild = dataSnapshots.next();
                String resultString = (String)dataSnapshotChild.getValue();


            }  

        }  

        @Override  
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                // for handling database error            
        }  
    });  
}
```