# Android - getValue from Firebase returns null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am setting the value of a child in Firebase, but when I get the value from Firebase the value is null. I don't understand why.

```
   database.child("User").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    int depositInteger = 0;
                    try {
                        depositInteger = Integer.parseInt(depositText.getText().toString().trim());
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        if (depositText.equals("")) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }


                    database.child(user.getDisplayName()).child("deposit").setValue(depositInteger);
                    Long previousDeposit = dataSnapshot.child("User").child(user.getDisplayName()).child("deposit").getValue(Long.class);
                    System.out.println("VAAAALUE: " + previousDeposit);


                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

[image]

Comment: Take reference from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44494430/retrieve-user-data-from-firebase-database/44497238#44497238

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set a value, you can use `setValue()` method directly on the reference like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference userRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(user.getDisplayName());
userRef.child("deposit").setValue(9); //Sets the value to 9
```

To get the value, please use the following code:

```
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        int deposit = dataSnapshot.child("deposit").getValue(Integer.class);
        Log.d("TAG", deposit);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Please see the correct `DatabaseReference` which contains `Users` and not only `User` as shown in your screen-shot.

Answer (score 1):

According your database structure the child you should reference is **Users** and in your code you are calling **User**. Fix that mistake...

```
//Replace child tag by Users to fix the error
database.child("Users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() { ...
```